# $3 \times 3$ matrix, singular, positive semidefinite, $\max$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, positive-semidefinite

Assume $A$ is a symmetric nonsingular positive semidefinite nonnegative $3 \times 3$-matrix. Let $\gamma_0$ be the maximal $\gamma \geq 0$ for which $A-\gamma E_{33}$ is positive semidefinite. Show that $\gamma_0=\frac{detA}{detA_{33}}$, where $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{12}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{13}&a_{23}&a_{33}
\end{pmatrix},$$ $$A_{33}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}\\
a_{12}&a_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix},$$
$$E_{33}=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I need some help with that. Is it possible to show with characteristic polynomial? I couldn't come to the end.

Comment: What exactly is $E_{33}$?

Comment: @Arthur@jflipp I made some edits above.

Comment: Since the matrices here are symmetric, a knee-jerk reflex action is to change to a basis where they are diagonal. But there is a trade-off, as diagonalizing $A$ makes $E_{33}$ non-diagonal. Maybe just diagonalize $A_{33}$ and not touch the third basis vector and $E_{33}$? Or plow through and diagonalize all of $A$, and just handle whatever happens to $E_{33}$? One won't know which approach is easiest without first trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if all its minors are nonnegative. In particular $A-\gamma E_{33}$ is positive semidefinite if and only if its determinant is nonnegative, where
$$\det(A-\gamma E_{33})=a_{13}\det A_{13}-a_{23}\det A_{23}+(a_{33}-\gamma)\det A_{33}=\det A-\gamma\det A_{33}.$$
So it follows that the maximal value of $\gamma$ for which $A-\gamma E_{33}$ is positive semidefinite is
$\frac{\det A}{\det A_{33}}$.